# UAC dialog unresponsive for two seconds

Tags: windows-7, windows, uac

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit and sometimes I experience about two second freeze when UAC dialog pops up. The computer stutters for about two seconds before showing the dialog and another two seconds after closing the dialog. The sound starts looping and mouse pointer can't be moved. This can be fixed with a reboot, but it's quite annoying since it happens every few days. When the problem appears, it'll be with all the UAC dialogs until you reboot the computer.

I'm running MSE and Outpost Firewall with defense mechanisms disabled. I do reboot my computer every night.

Comment: I don't even see a UAC dialog every week. What are you doing that's setting it off that often?

Comment: Perhaps not using the default insecure settings that whitelist MS stuff

Comment: Did you check/disable the Windows firewall after you installed Outpost?

Comment: CarlF: well, for example kX Project drivers prompt for access every time. I'm not really sure why. Well, and regedit once in a while since I do devel programs/installers/etc on this machine. Moab: Windows Firewall is turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of thing was a big problem when Vista came out due to video drivers.  Try turning off the secure desktop option (the third slider value in the UAC settings) and/or update your video drivers.

Comment: Running CCC 10.12. I guess I'll try 11.3/11.4 and no dimming. Can't really tell if they help, because the stutter doesn't appear always.

Comment: Well, I was thinking much older than that if that were the cause.  Can you try seeing if it happens with the Secure Desktop option turned off in the UAC settings?

Comment: Yes, I'm running UAC without secure desktop now. I'll let you know if it helps.